# Finding out which list element is clicked using jquery (list is added dynamically)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Case1: List is present in the html already

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

The clicked li element is detected using

```
$('#list1 li').bind('click', function(){
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

Above works fine.

Case 2:

Now if the list is added dyamically

```
<div id="testDiv">
</div>

var output = '<ul id="list1">' +
             '<li>One</li>' + 
             '<li>Two</li>' +
             '</ul>';

$('#testDiv').html(output);
```

I try to detect the clicked li element using same code

```
$('#list1 li').bind('click', function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

In this case, it does not detect

Comment: Look for "event delegation". See here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You asked the exact same question less than an hour ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('#testDiv').on('click', '#list1 li', function () {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```